# Does the writing $\int_\mathbb R \sup_{x\in I} f(x) \ \varphi(x) dx$ make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded function and let $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

I am wondering if this integral make sense:
$$\int_\mathbb R \sup_{x\in I} f(x) \ \varphi(x) dx,$$
where $I$ denotes an unbounded interval of $\mathbb R$.
I am confused by the fact that we are integrating over $x$ and simultaneously we are taking the supremum.

Anyone could please explain this point?
It is a common writing during my calc class.

Comment: There is a slight mess in notation caused by using $x$ both in the supremum and as integration variable, but as it’s written, $\sup_{x\in I} f(x)$ is just some constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't, as $x$ is called for two very different purposes at the same time. You must write $\sup_{y\in I}$ instead, and decide where this new dummy variable will go, by example you can write $f(y)$ instead of $f(x)$ and you will have that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sup_{y\in I}f(y)\varphi (x)\,d x=\sup_{y\in I}f(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi (x)\,d x
$$
Similarly you can write $f(y)\varphi (y)$, and so the integral diverges (except in the case that $\sup_{y\in I}f(y)\varphi (y)=0$).